# What is the purpose of objectWillChangeSequence compared to the onChange modifier in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The sample comes from a WWDC22 video called [The SwiftUI cookbook for navigation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10054/).

A `NavigationModel` is created to store the navigation path.

- When the view appears, the `NavigationModel` is loaded with SceneStorage's data if any exists.
- Whenever the `NavigationModel` changes, its data representation is saved in SceneStorage, by watching a custom `objectWillChangeSequence` computed property.

This last point intrigues me: why not just use the `.onChange` modifier? Like this:

```
.onChange(of: navModel.path) { _ in
    data = navModel.jsonData
}
```

NB: the `objectWillChangeSequence` property is defined like this:

```
var objectWillChangeSequence: AsyncPublisher<Publishers.Buffer<ObservableObjectPublisher>> {
    objectWillChange.buffer(size: 1, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropOldest).values
}
```

[image]

Comment: There are many approaches to do same thing, would you specify where is a problem?

Comment: Why on earth Apple illustrates its example with a property that is difficult to understand, especially for a beginner, when there is already a widely used `.onChange` modifier that solves the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes in the [sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_robust_navigation_structure_to_your_swiftui_app) shown in the video.

One mistake is the `Recipe` struct has `let id = UUID()` which means even if the navigation path is restored, the recipe that was previously viewed would never be found because it has a different `id` from when it was persisted.

We can quickly fix it with this:

```
struct Recipe: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return name
    }
```

Now the `@SceneStorage` will start working and we can test replacing it with `.onChange`.

We quickly find out that `NavigationModel` has more than `recipePath`, there is also `selectedCategory` and `columnVisibility`. If we were to use `onChange` with `jsonData` then we would be needlessly doing an encode just to check if there has been a change.

Comment: Can I ask u why should I need to store a navigation data/path instead of creating it on app launch? Does really make sense?

Comment: @GiuseppeMazzilli it gives the illusion that even if an app was killed, it was always running. But more importantly, if you want to support multi-window iPad apps, you need state restoration because otherwise the user will keep up opening tabs, that when killed, they will just go back to their original state as if they never had any content.